# how to add multiple object on array list

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I would like to add multiple objects to an ArrayList but I can't do it with my code. Here is the code I'm currently using. In the for loop, its adding the same object to the ArrayList 5 times. Why is this occurring?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class newBook {
    public int no;
    public String isim;

    public newBook(int no ,String isim){
        this.no = no;
        this.isim = isim;        
    }    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return " no = " + this.no +", name = " + this.isim;        
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){        
             Scanner klavye = new Scanner(System.in);
             int kitapNo = klavye.nextInt();
             String kitapName = klavye.next();            
             ArrayList<newBook> liste = new ArrayList<>();          
             for(int i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){               
                 liste.add( new newBook(kitapNo,kitapName));
                 //System.out.println("Çıkmak için -1 giriniz ");
                 //int i = klavye.nextInt();
             }             
        for (newBook liste1 : liste) {
            System.out.println(liste1);
        }             
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you intend to happen?

Comment: what is your confusion ?

Comment: @JonK a library automation user gonna add book with book no and book name its just for adding new book class variable re turkish  isim = name, liste = list, kitap = book

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder  i cant enter different book no and book name  on output  it shows same object 5 time

Comment: umm Kayaman answered well

Comment: I had no idea that this topic would become so surreal...

Answer (score 4):

They are not the same object, they just have the same content. You need to read the input from `klavye` inside the loop too.

Comment: I think this should be in comment.

Comment: This answers his question -> it's an answer (even though I usually don't bother writing out answers for simplest questions).

Comment: @Shivam I'm trying to figure out if you're trying to make a sarcastic point or if you're genuinely happy for me :D

Comment: I am laughing now, happy for OP and you both. I just read mine comment and found that was INSANE. #JyriBlasphemer Ohhh Really!!! @Kayman CLAPS..